# Foward Declarations in C#

Tags: c#, forward-declaration

I **really** like declaring all of my methods at the start of a class and would like to do so with forward declarations and then implement them further down. Is this possible in C#?

Ex:

```
private void Test();

private void Test()
{
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know.. what do you gain by doing that?

Comment: [The program does not contain forward declarations. Forward declarations are never needed, as declaration order is not significant.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664628(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Explain **why** you love forward declaration so much, and we could possibly help you, because while forward declaration does not exist in the language, there might be some other way. Forward declaration is a tool (and more often than none, a constraint), not an end.

Comment: It's not possible because it isn't necessary. Languages that do have this require it for one reason (single pass compilation) or another, never for readability. Look into interfaces and/or the outlining features in VS.

Comment: From a Delphi background where forward declarations are required, personally I find it much easier to get a quick overview of what a class can do by glancing at the methods all grouped together. Collapsible code in newer IDE's makes this less of an issue, but it's still a preference.

Comment: Don't bring too much Delphi baggage with you. New language, new rules, new tools.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can do this. Or you can kinda sorta do this. But for each of these possible "Solutions", **if it is for cosmetic reasons only** don't use these constructs.

One trick is to use a partial class with [partial methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6b0scde8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
partial class A
{
    partial void OnSomethingHappened(string s);
}

// This part can be in a separate file. 
partial class A
{
    /* Comment out this method and the program 
     will still compile.*/
    partial void OnSomethingHappened(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something happened: {0}", s);
    }
}
```

As highlighted in the referenced documentation, its uses are limited:

> A partial method has its signature defined in one part of a partial type, and its implementation defined in another part of the type. Partial methods enable class designers to provide method hooks, similar to event handlers, that developers may decide to implement or not. If the developer does not supply an implementation, the compiler removes the signature at compile time.
>
> The following conditions apply to partial methods:
>
> - Signatures in both parts of the partial type must match.
> - The method must return void.
> - No access modifiers are allowed. Partial methods are implicitly private.

As pointed out in [@Serv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29580745/2573395) and [@StanimirYakimov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29580734/2573395) answers, another "kinda sorta" construct that can be used is the declaration of an interface or pure abstract class, very similar to how you would declare one in c++:

```
public interface IA
{
    int GetTheOneAndOnlyNumber(); 
}

public abstract class AA
{
    protected abstract void OnSomethingHappened(string s);
}

public class A : AA, IA
{
    public int GetTheOneAndOnlyNumber()
    {
        return 42;
    }
    protected override void OnSomethingHappened(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

When switching from a language we know well to a new language, there are always specific idioms and constructs that we will miss. This does not mean that it is wise to try to emulate them with non-idiomatic constructs in the new language.

If you would like to have a condensed view of the structure of your code in Visual Studio, there are [several standard ways](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whks02wf(v=vs.120).aspx) of doing that, such as the Object Browser and Class View.

And if you search and look around, you will find other available tools that can help you with getting a quick overview of the structure of your code.

Comment: While this is possible in this very specific case, it is not very useful generally. Partial methods must return void, cannot have access modifiers, and cannot be abstract, virtual, or override.

Comment: Although creative, it will later be an order of a magnitude harder to maintain and is very limited.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I did not say this was a good idea. I would never do this myself.

Comment: @Alex I know. Just thought it was important to point out for future people reading this answer.

Comment: Thanks, this was a really well thought out answer. I guess I just need to let my Delphi instincts go.

Comment: @user1970794 glad that helped, and yes you need to let go :D  If you feel that this, or any of the other answers, sufficiently addressed your question, you may want to select it as "the answer".

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using interfaces

Just define which methods your class will use by inheriting from an interface. 
See this interface as a mixture of forward declarations and a contract. Classes inherting from an interface must implement all of its members.

```
public interface iSomeClass
{
    void MyMethod1();
    bool MyBoolMethod();
}


public class MyClass : iSomeClass
{
    public void MyMethod1()
    {
     //...
    }

    public bool MyBoolMethod()
    {
     //...
     return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer no it is not possible.
The reason is that there are no standalone functions in C# but classes with methods.

Also in other languages like C++ once you start using classes forward declaration of the methods themselves are not needed. It can be that the classes themselves need forward declarations in C++ but since you are talking about methods the comparison still stands.

Bottom line a class is completely defined by its methods in any order they are defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do things like this in C#. I am not sure why you would really want to anyway. Having the declaration and definition in one place is simple and easier to understand

Doing something like this is required in some other languages, but forcing that pattern in C# probably isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not do it. You can only declare abstract methods like this. Otherwise it will give you an error.

I tried and it gave me

```
Error   1   'Project.SomeClass.ABC()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial
```

Only abstract methods can be defined like this, abstract methods need only a prototype to be overridden.
This is valid:

```
public abstract void ABC();
```

Answer (score 0):

Forward declaration is not possible in C# classes. It's possible only in Interfaces and if your method is `abstract`. Something like this is allowed

```
abstract void Draw();
```